# mongodb - aggregation with $match $in with a $lookup pipeline

Tags: javascript, mongodb

If I have the following object as `obj`:

```
{
    "abc1": "xyz1",
    "abc2": "xyz2",
    "abc3": "xyz3"
}
```

and I want to do an aggregation with something like:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { 
        "$match": { 
            "_id": {
                $in:
                    Object.keys(obj)
            }
        } 
    },
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "subdocument",
            "pipeline": [
                { 
                    "$match": { 
                        "_id": ObjectId(matching_value) 
                    } 
                },
            ],
            "as": "subdocument"
        }
    },
    { "$unwind": "$subdocument" }
])
```

how do I get the `$lookup` pipeline to match the object key to match the object value? Is it possible?

So it would be a single db call version of this:

```
let obj = {
    "abc1": "xyz1",
    "abc2": "xyz2",
    "abc3": "xyz3"
}

for (let key in obj)
{
    db.collection.aggregate([
        { 
            "$match": { 
                "_id": 
                    ObjectId(key)
            } 
        },
        {
            "$lookup": {
                "from": "subdocument",
                "pipeline": [
                    { 
                        "$match": { 
                            "_id": ObjectId(obj[key]) 
                        } 
                    },
                ],
                "as": "subdocument"
            }
        },
        { "$unwind": "$subdocument" }
    ])
}
```

Example collections

```
db.maindocuments
[
    {
        _id: "abc1",
        data: "data"
    },
    {
        _id: "abc2",
        data: "data"
    },
    {
        _id: "abc3",
        data: "data"
    }
]
```

```
db.subdocuments
[
    {
        _id: "xyz1",
        data: "data"
    },
    {
        _id: "xyz2",
        data: "data"
    },
    {
        _id: "xyz3",
        data: "data"
    }
]
```

Comment: What is `matching_value`? and what does `_id` contain here `"_id": {
                $in:
                    Object.keys(obj)
            }`?

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet the `matching_value` is meant to correspond to the "value" in the object in the previous passage, i.e. `xyz1` for `abc1`. So the `$in` would contain the values `["abc1", "abc2", "abc3"`

Comment: `matching_value = {
    "abc1": "xyz1",
    "abc2": "xyz2",
    "abc3": "xyz3"
}` ? if yes then what is `_id` of `subdocument` contains?

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet not quite, I'll make an update on what I want, except it would be in a for loop.

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet updated with a for loop representation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I can see there is no relation in both the collections. and that's why `$lookup` won't work as there is no matching keys in the documents.

Therefore, You can do using `async` `await`

```
const obj = {
  "abc1": "xyz1",
  "abc2": "xyz2",
  "abc3": "xyz3"
}

for (let key in obj) {
  const data = await db.collection.findOne({ _id: key })
  const subdocument = await db.subdocument.findOne({ _id: obj[key] })
  data.subdocument = subdocument
}
```

Comment: will it match one to one? kinda looks like each document will have all the of subdocuments

Comment: No it doesn't . Can you show what your `_id` for each document contains?

Comment: well that's what the `for` loop was representing. I've got these relational data that I've kept in a mysql database, which indicates inheritance. So each "key" is actually the _id of document in one collection, and the "value" is the _id of a document in another collection that I want to put in as a subdocument.

Comment: To give a bit more context, I have items and item_templates. Each item may have an item_template (and it may not). The "main" _id is the item and the "subdocument" _id is the item_template. So it's always going to be at most a one to one.

Comment: Does the main document(db.collection) contains these values `"xyz1", "xyz2", "xyz3"` ?

Comment: yes, each one is meant to represent an individual document _id.

Comment: Please show some sample data. Then only I can suggest you the best way

Comment: Added example collections. But don't worry about it too much if you can't find a way I'll work something else out.

Comment: okay, so I guess this will require a for loop then (it is quite messy in terms of data so I was kinda expecting it).

Comment: hmm. I have mentioned the reason in the answer. Why `$lookup` won't work here